# How would I go about changing the way the Rider IDE formats my C# code?

Tags: c#, rider

So right now my if else statements are automatically formatted like:

[image: Rider IDE formatting I don't want.]

but I want them to be formatted like:

[image: Rider IDE formatting I want.]

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be configured in `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | C# | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Arrangement of Statements | Place "else" on new line true`.